# Why immutability of super class is not forced in child class?

Tags: kotlin, immutability

You can break immutabiliy of super class, even if you declare the immutable fields with `val` in interface or abstract class.

```kotlin
interface Foo {
    val bar: String // immutable
}

class FooImpl : Foo {
    override var bar: String = "bar" // mutable

    init {
        bar = "changed"
    }
}

println(FooImpl().bar) // changed
```

I expected above code will occurs compile error, but it works.
Why is this possible in kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val` doesn’t mean *immutable*. It means *read-only*. Even if you don’t override it as a `var` you could make it a `val` that returns a different value each time.

So expanding it to also be writable isn’t breaking any contract.

There is no way to enforce an open property to be immutable. Best you can do is use documentation that declares that it will not behave correctly if it doesn’t return the same value every time.

Comment: This is one of the *features* of Kotlin that I dislike the most. The use of the keyword `val` in my mind means immutable and it breaks the least astonishing principle for me, but as Tenfour04 says, it means read-only. And I would say, to make other people life easier, if you use val, make it behave in an immutable way too. At least in my experience most Kotlin devs expect a val to be immutable.

Comment: It’s a critical feature for OOP properties to have. The getter can be customized and the setter can have reduced scope or be deferred to specific implementations. I don’t see why it’s astonishing. Nowhere in the documentation do they call it immutable, and the first page of the documentation demonstrates custom getters so it is a lesson you learn in the first five minutes of reading about the language.

Comment: that was just my opinion :). For a me the concept of a *value* is immutable while a variable, well, it's in the name. To add to the confusion and as an example, in typescript a `readonly` modifier makes it immutable too. I'm not talking about the docs, but just what *I* consider would the expected way of a language to behave.

Comment: For the language to be able to guarantee full immutability would arguably be very useful — but it's hard to see how it could be added without major overhead and/or incompatibility. It would probably need to be fitted into the type system, which would be a very significant language change. Reworking the standard library to use it where appropriate would probably break lots of existing code; but if not, it wouldn't be very useful. Ditto every other existing library. And (if experience with `const` in C is anything to go by) it's likely to bring lots of awkward corner cases and confusion.

Comment: @gidds I can think of some use cases where it would be helpful. I don't think it would necessarily involve types. There could be a modifier that enforces that a property implementation must use a backing field and have no setter. But even if they did consider that early on, Java compatibility probably would have killed the idea--can't force the Java compiler to obey a Kotlin keyword.

Comment: @Tenfour04 For compatibility with Java (and other JVM languages), it could look for and trust an annotation, like it does for nullability — not an ideal solution, but probably good enough*. But I think it would need to be in the type system, to support deep (recursive) immutability. (For example, not only would a List have to fix the references it held; the objects it referred to would all have to be immutable, and so on.) Both methods and their callers would need to know what they could change, and there are probably a range of optimisations that the compiler could apply as a result.

Comment: (* Of course, this wouldn't absolutely guarantee that non-Kotlin code couldn't mutate something. But then neither could Kotlin code, in the presence of Reflection etc. A best-effort basis — like for nullability — would still work well.)

Answer (score 0):

From the [language spec:](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/inheritance.html#overriding)

> A property declaration *D* which overrides property declaration *B* should satisfy the following conditions.
>
> - Mutability of *D* is not stronger than mutability of *B* (where read-only `val` is stronger than mutable `var`);
> - Type of *D* is a subtype of type of *B* ; except for the case when both *D* and *B* are mutable (`var`), then types of *D* and *B* must be equivalent.

So your overriding property can add mutability, and also use a more specific subtype (e.g. `Int` instead of `Number`) **so long as** the declaration isn't a `var` (so you can't write a `Double` to it via the interface).

One way you could look at it, is your original `val` is sort of declaring a `getBar(): String` function which you're overriding. By making it a `var`, you're also defining a `setString(string)` function *in your own class*.

If you try to access your object `as Foo` then that setter doesn't exist, because it's not (implicitly) defined in the interface. It's a separate function on your class, just conveniently expressed by tweaking the property definition (in a defined, restricted way)